# ListView with the fixed number of items to display

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

is there any standard way in Android for creating a list view covering content by width, but with the height big enough for displaying a fixed number of rows?

For example, I would want my scrollable listview to pop up in the middle of a screen/activity displaying exactly 6 items out of 20 at a time.

Comment: What if someone is using your app on a large tablet?  Do you really want to restrict the user to seeing 6 rows at at time?  Sounds rather limiting.

Comment: That should be fine.  My items are going to wrap images different per size/density, I don't think it will be too bad.

Comment: Well, I don't really have an answer for you.  But I think the way to do it is to size your items so 6 of them exactly fill the space allocated for the list.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder() {  
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data, String textRepresentation) {  
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) view
                .getLayoutParams();
        params.height = Math.round(mScreenHeight/ 6); 

        return true;  
        }  
    }  
);
```

Comment: Sounds like this code stretches each of the views to make 6 of them to fit the full screen?  but I don't really want to cover full screen, perhaps I can do something using getView/getCount methods of the ListView adapter.

Answer (score 1):

The solution from [wrap_content for a listview's width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547154/wrap-content-for-a-listviews-width) works ( see getWidestView ). Same thing can be applied for height ( measure a height using fake parent and *6 after )