# Android LinearLayout weight and wrap_content of ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-linearlayout

I want to create a two-column layout. The first column should be a `List`, and it should take as much width as they want. The second column should be `FrameLayout` and should occupy all the remaining space.
I can achieve the desired, if I use the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="ru.automatikaplus.caliberadmin.TestActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorGreen"/>

    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**And the result:**

[image: Screenshot_1]

`FrameLayout` is green for clarity.

**BUT!** If I change `RecyclerView` to `ListView` or anything else - this layout doesn't work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="ru.automatikaplus.caliberadmin.TestActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorGreen"/>

    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

`FrameLayout` is gone, `ListView` take all the space. Why?

How can I make layout from first screenshot with `ListView` instead of `RecycleView`?

**Edit1:**
This scheme works perfectly in simple cases. For example there are three `TextViews`, two with `wrap_content` and one with `weight=1`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Test1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorGreen"
        android:text="Test2"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Test3"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

It works like a charm, middle `TextView` takes all free space:

[image]

But this doesn't work with `ListView`.
I need `ListView` to take only space he needs, not 0.3 of screen, not hard-coded value of dp, just a `wrap_content`.

**Edit2:** List item layout is follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"/>
```

**Edit3:** I can say you more: if you remove all the stuff from second example and leave only `CoordinatorLayout` with `ListView` inside it, the `ListView` **still** takes fullscreen regardless of wrap_content width. Why?

Comment: please see my answer and let me know about result

Comment: @Dhiraj commented. Unfortunately this is not what I need.

Comment: can you post the list item xml? might be there would be some view which has width = match_parent

Comment: @Exerion can i see your list item xml???

Comment: @SAIR edited question, added list item xml

Comment: i have just copied you layout with recycler view and list view. and even in layout editor it show that recycler view  is warped content. but list view takes the full screen.

Comment: @SAIR that is exactly what question is about. What can I do to make ListView behave like RecycleView is this case?

Comment: i am going to run a sample adapter. just let me complete that. then i will share my findings

Comment: @SAIR, also take a look on **Edit3** section. This is weird.

Comment: @Exerion can you take look of this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295080/android-wrap-content-is-not-working-with-listview

Comment: @Exerion see the accepted answer on that link it will might help you

Comment: @Exerion i tried with sample using listview it is but not working

Comment: @Dhiraj `to be as wide as the widest of its children` - he said. Items of my list are the same width and they are small, because I fill them just with test strings like "Test 1". But still - fullscreen.

Comment: seems like ListView just can't have wrap_content width. But RecycleView can. I suppose I have to use it instead of simple ListView.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113413/discussion-between-dhiraj-and-exerion).

Comment: @Exerion: yes you are quite right. listview does not wrap to its child views. i have faced the same issue with grid view. i suggest you to use recycler view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is said [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6547838/4657518) and [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270278/layout-width-of-a-listview), standart android ListView can not have `wrap_content` as a width since the width of child elements may be different.
As a workaround, one should use [RecycleView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) instead of ListView.

Answer (score 0):

change your code for listview in xml as follows

```
    <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.3" />
```

As you are using wrap_content for first child in linear layout and layout_weight for second child in linear layout so it might be possible that it will lead to weird behaviour.WRAP_CONTENT takes the space exactely to item size so in your case it might be possible that list requires all the space of the screen

Comment: No, list content is very narrow, but it still takes all space. Your solution as long as a @Mehta's solution make a list always be the same width = 0.3 of the width of the screen no matter what, this is not what I need.

Answer (score -1):

try this by applying weight to your **ListView** and **Frame Layout**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout >
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:background="@color/colorGreen"/>

    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```